# startActivity to relaunch HomeActivity from another activity in the same application doesn't work in Gingerbread

Tags: android, android-2.3-gingerbread, start-activity

In my application I have used some code from the iosched 2012 app. In specific the starting workflow is the following:

1.The user presses the launcher icon of the app

2.HomeActivity checks if the user is authenticated. If he/she is not, it starts the Authentication activity, passing it intent to it and finishes itself

3.When the login process is successful, the authenction activity starts an activity in order to start the HomeActivity and finishes itself

4.HomeActivity checks again if the user is authenticated and displays the home screen of the application.

The following code works like a charm in API Level > 11. Today, I tried the app in a Gingerbread and it fails. Step 3 works, but although the HomeActivity starts it's not brought to front. You have to use the recent list and choose the application in order to see the homeactivity and its now displayed content.

Here's the code and check from the HomeActivity in the oncCreate method

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if(!AccountUtils.isSystemAuthenticated(this)) {
        AccountUtils.startSystemAuthentication(this, getIntent());
        finish();
    } else if(!AccountUtils.isAppAuthenticated(this)) {
        AccountUtils.startAppAuthentication(this, getIntent());
        finish();
    } 

    if(isFinishing()) {
        return;
    }

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            ...
    }
 }
```

The method invoked in the Authentication activity after the login process is completed

```
protected void handleLoginSuccess(LoginServiceResponse response, String username, String password) {
if(....) {
        if(mFinishIntent != null) {
            mFinishIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
            mFinishIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
            mFinishIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
                        | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                startActivity(mFinishIntent);
        }

        finish();
        } else {
            super.handleLoginSuccess(response, username, password);
        }
    }
```

Where the mFinishIntent member variable is the intent passed from the HomeActivity (using getIntent())

As I mentioned, in API Level > 11, this works well, and the breakpoint in HomeActivity's onCreted method is hit twice, while in a Gingerbread phone, is hit only once (only when the application starts).

Do I have to use another flag or do you have any other idea of what's going on?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What is probably happening is that the activity is only created when the app is started and then when you go back to it from the Authentication activity, it is simply resumed. Try putting the authentication checking code in HomeActivity in the onResume() method.

Here is some more info:  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ProcessLifecycle

Comment: Thanks. I am gonna try that. I just realized that the same happens (I thought I was missing something in my app) with the iosched app. I tested it in a 2.3.3 emulator and after authenticating the HomeActivity is not started again.

Comment: It didn't work. The HomeActivity is destroyed (onDestroy is called) since finished() is called. Nevetheless, I still can't understand why the same code works in ICS for i.e.